# When Does the Segue Destination Call viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, xcode9, lldb

```
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let strategyPicker=segue.destination as! StrategyViewController
    strategyPicker.folder=self.folder
    NSLog("Tried to pass \(self.folder) into \(String(describing: strategyPicker.folder))")
}
```

Trying to debug in lldb, it seems that simply assigning segue.destination is triggering the viewDidAppear in the destination view controller.  I am getting a fatal error in viewDidAppear in the destination before passing the folder.  I understand that any initializer code has to run (and it does--a couple of fields are correctly initialized according to lldb e commands).  It just does not make sense that the viewDidAppear is called before the prepareForSegue finishes.

I have breakpoints on the strategyPicker.folder assignment and the NSLog and neither triggers before the error in the destination viewDidAppear.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` aren't called before `prepare(for:sender:)` is called.

The function you have shown isn't being called as it doesn't have the correct method signature. You want

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let strategyPicker=segue.destination as? StrategyViewController {
        strategyPicker.folder=self.folder
        NSLog("Tried to pass \(self.folder) into \(String(describing: strategyPicker.folder))")
    }
}
```

Also, since you mentioned a crash in your destination view controller, it is likely that you are force-unwrapping `folder` there; you should probably re-think this and code defensively.  Conditionally unwrap and display an appropriate error message if `folder` is `nil`.

Comment: My apologies!  The code was written in Swift 2, ignored through Swift 3 and manually--incorrectly--converted to Swift 4.